# Grafana with mod operator (Remainder)

Tags: grafana

Can I use MOD operator in a timeseries chart and how? I didn't find in the documentation (maybe I'm searching it wrong).

Example:

I have one chart that gives a number and it will always increment (let's say 98) I'd like to see the remainder(mod) of 10 which would be 8 ;
Therefore the chart would rotate from 0 to 9 as my main metric increases

Comment: which timeline database / datasource are you using?

Comment: @JensBaitinger, This data I'm using zabbix(remote command) to query the number of rows in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana visualizes data from the time series query usually. Check documentation of used time series DB and search how to use MOD operator in the query there. So Grafana receives data after MOD operation and you won't need any data transformation on the Grafana level.